# Update Database From Check Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a `GridView` with a `ItemTemplate` field that is capturing the `ID` of the checkbox that is checked, and I have `AutoPostBack=false` so that it is not updated immediately, and I have a `asp:Button` that I want to use `C#` to run an update statement to update a database with all of the `ID's` from the checked checkboxes.  I am setting things up but I keep getting an error of

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

when the button is pressed, more specifically it is this line of code that throws the error:

```
string dbrowtoupdate = ((Label)row.FindControl("dataid")).Text;
```

And this is the HTML\C# for my grid, it's source is a SQL Query and it populates perfectly.

```
<tr>
<td valign="top">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridviewtrythis" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  >
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Full Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("dataid") %>'   ID="dataid" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("cbox")) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>                                
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdateDB" Text="Add" OnClick="btnUpdateDB_Click" />
</td>
</tr>

protected void btnUpdateDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridviewtrythis.Rows)
    {
        string dbrowtoupdate = ((Label)row.FindControl("dataid")).Text;
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
}
```

Comment: Try splitting the offending line of code into 2 lines.  One to get the label from the row, then the next to get the string value from the label if it's not null.  I'm guessing it's not finding the Label control, therefore you're trying to get .Text from a null variable.

Comment: @Ageonix - How would I do such?

Comment: @Ageonix - that removed the error but it is not actually capturing the value from the row in the grid.

Comment: I slightly modified the line that looks for the control. Is it still null if you try this method instead?  var labelToUpdate = row.FindControl("dataid") as Label;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the offending line of code into this:

```
Label labelToUpdate = row.FindControl("dataid") as Label;
if (labelToUpdate)
{
   string dbrowtoupdate = labelToUpdate.Text;
   if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

        }
}
```

I'm willing to bet labelToUpdate is null so it won't get into the loop.  Put a breakpoint at the spot you're searching for the label control and inspect the "row" variable if you want to see what controls are contained in that row, but changing this to use "as Label" and then checking for null before getting the .Text should protect you from the Null Reference moving forward.